# neo4j CYPHER - Dynamically run a FOREACH during JSON import depending on whether JSON element has a certain property

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, py2neo, pubmed

To import XML data into a neo4j DB I first parse the XML to a python dictionary and then use CYPHER queries like this:
(The pmid has a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT)

```
WITH $pubmed_dict as pubmed_article
UNWIND pubmed_article as particle
    MERGE (p:Publication {pmid: particle.MedlineCitation.PMID.text})
    ON CREATE SET p.title = COALESCE (particle.MedlineCitation.Article.Journal.Title, particle.MedlineCitation.Article.ArticleTitle)
    ON MATCH SET p.title = COALESCE (particle.MedlineCitation.Article.Journal.Title, particle.MedlineCitation.Article.ArticleTitle)

FOREACH (author IN particle.MedlineCitation.Article.AuthorList.Author |
  MERGE (a:Author {last_name: COALESCE(author.LastName, 'LAST NAME MISSING!'), first_name: COALESCE(author.ForeName, 'FIRST NAME MISSING!')})
  MERGE (p)<-[:WROTE]-(a)      
)

FOREACH (ref IN particle.MedlineCitation.CommentsCorrectionsList.CommentsCorrections |
  MERGE (cited_p:Publication {pmid: COALESCE (ref.PMID.text, 'NO-PMID')}) 
  MERGE (cited_p)<-[:REFERENCES]-(p)   
)
```

My **particle** has the following dictionary structure:

[image: particle dictionary structure]

What I want to achieve in the second FOREACH loop is: 
IF there is a `particle.MedlineCitation.CommentsCorrectionsList.CommentsCorrections` list 
AND IF it has a map with `PMID.text`, 
I want that nothing happens if a publication with the given PMID already exists and I want otherwise that new nodes are created with the given PMID. In both cases I want that the node gets a relationship REFERENCES from the initially created p:Publication at the start of the query.

I have not found the syntax for such a case yet and the only workaround so far using the function `COALESCE (ref.PMID.text, 'NO-PMID')})` always creates new :REFERENCES relationships to nodes which have a CommentsCorrectionsList without a PMID.

Who has a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CASE WHEN THEN` to create an (non)-empty collection and use FOREACH on that, which is basically like an conditionally executed block.

e.g.

```
FOREACH (_ IN case when exists(p.foo) then [true] else [] end |
  ....
)
```

Comment: What is [true] supposed to mean? [true] gives `Type mismatch: expected a map but was Boolean('true')` 

With this approach I also can't check dynamically. In pseudocode what I need is 
`FOR particle.MedlineCitation.CommentsCorrectionsList.CommentsCorrections AS ref IF ref HAS attribute == PMID: THEN MERGE using pmid ELSE do nothing`
I don't see how I can get this to work with the given example

Comment: as you can see in the screenshot, CommentsCorrections is a list which has numbered maps which **might** have a PMID map with a property _text_ which gives us the needed string